# Wordpress Contact form 7 Plugin not working in Default/Normal Setup

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I can't submit a form in contact form 7 it always say's that "**There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.** in red font color and background" I can't find what is the cause of the problem either the updated WordPress is the problem or the contact form 7 plugin itself is the problem because I set my contact form in the normal/default set up and still, the error message is recurring. As of this moment, my WordPress website is on my local server.

Hope you can enlighten me about my problem with Contact Form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your contact form is working properly problem is that because your site is in localhost it can't send the mail from localhost.

Comment: In localhost email is not working so it show above error when you move your website to live then mail should working fine. check this - https://contactform7.com/faq/i-get-an-error-message-with-a-red-border-so-how-can-i-solve-this/

Comment: to check that your form is submitting the data or not, install the cf7db  plugin it will show your submitted data in admin panel.. You can get the plugin from here "https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cf7-db"

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar I move my website from localhost to live server and the contact form 7 is now working properly. You're right, the contact form 7 is not working when it is in the localhost. Thank you for enlightening me about how to solve my problem it helps a lot. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @MukeshPanchal Yes, you are right. I transfered my website from localhost to live server and the contact form 7 now is working awesome. Thanks for sharing your solution about my problem. It helps a lot and I can move forward to my next task. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @MelvinRey In localhost to send mail you have to install wp_mail_smtp plugin after configuring it your contact form 7 will send mail from localhost also

Answer (score 0):

your contact form is working properly. problem is that because your site is in localhost it can't send the mail from localhost. 
to check that your form is submitting the data or not, install the cf7db plugin it will show your submitted data in admin panel.. You can get the plugin from here [advanced cf7 db](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cf7-db)

In localhost to send mail you have to install wp_mail_smtp plugin after configuring it your contact form 7 will send mail from localhost also. You can get the smtp plugin from here. [wp-mail-smtp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)